# Incorrect positioning in Google Earth Engine after exporting from Google Earth Engine

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine

I have an image loaded in Google Earth Engine and I want to save an enlarged area around it both as a feature collection and another image. I use below code for this purpose and it works fine and objects overlay correctly when I add the image (original image), box_fc, and box2X layers on GEE map. The original image projection is 'Albers_Conical_Equal_Area'.

```
var proj = image.projection()
var box = image.geometry()
var features = [ee.Feature(box.buffer(2500).bounds(0.001, proj=proj), {'Value': 0})];
var box_fc = ee.FeatureCollection(features)
var box2X = box_fc.reduceToImage({
  properties: ['Value'],
  reducer:ee.Reducer.first()
  }).reproject(proj)
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: box_fc,
  description: 'box2X',
  fileFormat: 'SHP'
})
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: box2X,
  description: 'box2X',
  region: box_fc,
  scale: 30
})
```

However, when I load the exported shape and image I see they are far apart. The shapefile (box_fc) is aligned correctly with the original image, but image (box2X) not. When I look at the image properties, the projection and extent are also correct, but it fails to display it correctly.

What is wrong here?

On the shapefile properties in ArcGIS Desktop, there are two question marks (??) after extent values.

What is it for?

---

I found that actually the 'box2X' image has not been exported properly and it looks like my understanding of reprojection is not correct. When I load the exported 'box2X' again into Google Earth engine and display it on the map, it is displaced similar to what I see in ArcGIS Desktop. I don't understand why before export it is displayed correctly in GEE, but not after export.

Comment: Please provide all the properties which you have reviewed to be correct in the question body, since it seems that they may be suspect.

Comment: I mentioned that the projection and extent of image box2X are correct and all objects overlay correctly in Google Earth Engine, but box2X is not overlaid on the other items correctly when displaying in ArcGIS Desktop. Do I need to check anything else?

Comment: This appears to now be a Google Earth Engine, rather than ArcMap, issue so I updated your tags.

Comment: Could you share code that defines the `image` variable, so that others can try to reproduce you issue?

Comment: Sure. The sample image can be loaded from this link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/shshheydari/Samp00_0000